# A difficulty in understanding a part of a paragraph in P.41 in Guillemin & Pollack (2)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

The paragraph is given below:

[image]

**But I do not understand:**

1-In the forth line why we can not have the case $df_{x} =$ constant other than 0, could anyone explain this for me please?

2-In the sixth line how f is simply **the first coordinate function**, could anyone give me a concrete example for describing this please?

3-In the tenth line I could not understand why the authors said **"But if $f(x)$ ia an extreme value, then obviously $f$ can not be a coordinate function near x"** , could anyone explain this statement for me please may be by a concrete example?

thank!

Comment: 1.  $df_x$ is a *linear* map of vector spaces, so how many such constant maps could it be?

Comment: you mean $f$ is a linear map of vector spaces or $df$? @Randall

Comment: Check the definitions:  given $f: X \to Y$ a smooth map, $df_x$ is a linear transformation $df_x: T_xM \to T_{f(x)}N$.

Comment: So by this definition since the differential(derivative) of a linear map is the linear map itself .... I do not know the answer for your first question .... I am confused.@Randall

Comment: No one said $f$ was "linear."

Comment: So I can say that the answer for your first question that $df_{x}$ has the general form $ax +b$  ....hence it can be of the form a only .... correct?@Randall

Comment: No.  We are talking about linear transformations of vector spaces.  You need a very thorough understanding of linear algebra to study manifolds.  In G-P, this occurs as early as page 8.

Comment: I have reread page 8 but I did not found an answer to my question or yours .... may be because my mother tongue is not english so I am not understanding @Randall

Comment: You are confusing the concept of linear function from elementary mathematics with the concept of a linear transformation of vector spaces that occurs in linear algebra. There is a connection between the two, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: Okay justin ....could you please when you have time tell me the differences and the connections between them @JustinYoung ..... your answer was succinct thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The only constant linear map is the zero map. (2) The claim in the sixth line is essentially the implicit function theorem. (3) Consider $f(x)=x^2$. No change of coordinates will turn this into $x$ near $0$.

Comment: why the only constant linear map is the zero map?

Comment: How it is the implicit function theorem?

Comment: do not understand the answer of (3)